# Why does resizing an image smaller than the original cause the filesize to increase?

Tags: coldfusion, jpeg, coldfusion-2018

I only resize images where they are bigger than the prescribed size like such:

```
<cfset BodyImgMainW = 670 />
<cfset BodyImgMainH = 670 />
<cfimage name="BodyImg" source="c:\sample_1365x768.jpg"/>

<cfif BodyImg.width GT BodyImgMaxW OR BodyImg.height GT BodyImgMaxH>
    <cfif BodyImg.width GT BodyImgMainW>
      <cfset ImageResize(BodyImg, BodyImgMainW, "", "highestQuality")/>
    <cfelseif BodyImg.height GT BodyImgMainH>
      <cfset ImageResize(BodyImg, "", BodyImgMainH, "highestQuality")/>
    </cfif>
    <cfimage source="#BodyImg#" action="write" destination="C:\sample_670x377.jpg" overwrite="yes" quality="1" format="jpg"/>
</cfif>
```

The original image I uploaded for testing was 1,365px × 768px and file size of 36.4KB. But once its been resized to 670px x 377px it ends up with a file size of 89.5KB.

Why does it increase in file size when the image is actually smaller? Is there a way to tell ColdFusion not to do anything to the image other than just make it smaller?

ORIGINAL IMAGE 1,200px × 800px @ 192.3KB:
[image: ORIGINAL IMAGE]

RESIZED IMAGE 670px × 447px @ 238.3KB:
[image: RESIZED IMAGE]

Comment: Check the "quality" attribute.  My guess is that the original is compressed, but you are resiziing it using "highestQuality" and then automatically saving without defining the quality... so it defaults to 1 (or 100%) quality (ie, no compression.)

As an alternative, we've been using ColdFusion w/GraphicsMagick (since CF8) to avoid issues regarding various java limitations: non-standard image palettes, wrong extensions, memory issues, transparency, file size and performance. If you have the ability to install & use it on your server, CFC & CFTags are available.

Comment: The original is probably compressed, but JPEG compression is destructive/lossy so it can't be 'uncompressed'. Therefore I just can't get my head around why an image half the size at 100% quality of the original image could have a bigger file size. GraphsMagick looks good - is there something else I need to make it work with CF tags?

Comment: Does it happen with other images - or just this one? Is it the image one you can post on S.O.?

Comment: @Ageax yes it does, not all, but quite a few. I have just uploaded an example of a car. The original image size is 1,200px × 800px @ 192.3KB. After CF resized the image to 670px x 447px the file size increases to 238.3 KB

Comment: @volumeone - Downloading the original gives a size of 192.0KB and after  resizing to 670x447 yields 59KB. But since it was uploaded, we may not be working with the same "original".

Comment: @Ageax I think it is the same original.... 192KB is the same file size. Resizing it in photoshop or another program will probably make it 59KB which is what I would like.... but CF makes the file bigger. Is CF just no good at this? What is it 'adding' to a substantially smaller image that is making the file size larger?

Comment: @volumeone - Well, I get 59KB under 2018. So something is different... Either our code/environment or possibly igmur modifying uploaded images (iirc, they do with larger images).

Comment: I edited my post. I missed out the key attribute that is causing the file size increase which is `quality="1"`. The default is `0.75` for JPEG quality, but I don't see why maintaining 100% quality of the original image causes a smaller image to be bigger in file size? If I remove the `quality` attribute and use the default `0.75` setting then I also get 59KB file size... but that is not only resizing but also compressing an already compressed original image.

Comment: This is the option that I mentioned (quality).  We never set it to "1" as it always generates files that are needlessly too large.

Comment: @volumeone - I don't follow what you mean by that last part. "quality" == "compression quality".  So it still applies, even if you're using quality=1, and no resizing whatsoever. What's wrong with the resulting images when you use quality=0.75?

Comment: @Ageax If you have an image that you compress to 50% quality in photoshop, and then you resize it down and save it again at 50% quality.... you're going to end up with 25% quality of the original image in the resized image right? It's like double compression which affects the quality of the image on high DPI displays considerably. For me 0.75 looks okay, but on a high-DPI device you can tell the quality is not quite good enough. Have I misunderstood JPEG quality settings?

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR**

JPEG has by its nature has artifacts. Compressing an image in general makes artifacts. Doing both makes lots of artifacts. When you saved the image, lots of space was used to encode artifacts.

---

The full story is long, but let me give the half baked version. JPEG images are bit mapped images, but they are not an exact copy of the original bit map. So what exactly are they?

Take you image, and rather than dealing with 1x1 pixels, consider a 8 x 8 block. In the upper left corner make that single pixel perfect when compared to the original. As for the other 63, create a mathematical approximation of what that should be (See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform). Depending on how much detail you want, more and more of the remaining 63 bits will be exactly right as opposed to close.

Now that all the data has been reduced, perform some basic lossless compression

---

Now let's take a look at what you did. You took and image, it was expanded out to 1365 x 768. That expansion did not create a perfect image. Some of the pixels were off because that is how JPEG works.

When you strunk it down, it was not a mathematical half. Which means the resulting pixels. A single pixel was not an average of what was 4 pixels (interpolation). So you are now averaging a lot of pixels. Keep in mind only 1 in 64 was actually correct.

A new image is created. It also has an 8 x 8 block. But its 8 x 8 block came also has noise from the original encoding and from the interpolation. The encoder cannot know what was a part of the expected image and what was noise. Hence it wants to encode all of the image so that it will accurately represent what it was handed. Encoding all this noise takes up space.

Comment: I never expanded the image to 1365x768... that is the original size of the image before any resizing/processing. The reason for making a small version is to increase page load speed on a results page... which is now defeated entirely if the preview image is bigger than the original in terms of file size!

Comment: Your answer addresses why JPG is causes artifacts... so is there a better format to use? PNG is really big. GIF quality is poor for photos.

Comment: When a JPEG is being processed, part of the process is to generate an uncompressed version. In a sense, you did expand it.

Comment: I don't understand - the original file as uploaded by the user goes to the server. No processing is done on that image at all. It is then resized with a copy written to the server... so only if the resizing occurs does CF do any processing of the image.

Comment: `ImageResize()` is not a one step process. The data has to be in intermediate states.